# Display assigned terms with link

Tags: widgets, tags, terms

I want to display product assigned terms, wrapped in link/anchor MarkUp, in my sidebar on a page as a widget. I am not getting the correct tag URL. Code returns visited product URL instead of listed tags URL.

Here is the problematic part of the code. What is the correct use of `get_the_terms()`?

```
$custom_terms = get_the_terms( 0, 'product_tag' );
if ( $custom_terms ) {
    foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {
        echo '<a href="'
            . esc_url( $term_link )
            . '" style="font-size: 8pt;">'
            . $custom_term->name
            . '</a>';
    }
}
```

I guess that something i wrong with `esc_url( $term_link )`, but what?

Comment: $term_link is not set

Comment: Thank you Mark. You were right. I will post correct snippet now.

Comment: *Note*: Only because a question contains the word Woocommerce it doesn't justify close and/or down-votes. Just saying..

Comment: `$term_link` is still not set. The correct snippet appears to have never been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the return value of `get_the_terms()` can be of the type of

```
array|WP_Error
```

Your snippet should check if you get the correct type returned

```
$terms = get_the_terms( 0, 'product_tag' );
if (
    ! is_wp_error( $terms )
    AND is_array( $terms )
    AND ! empty( $terms )
    )
{
    foreach( $terms as $term )
        printf(
            '<a href="%s" style="font-size: 8pt; margin-right:5px;">%s</a>',
            esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ),
            $term
        );
}
```

Comment: Hi Kaiser. 
Thank you for the contribution.

I make it your way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark, I solve this successfully.

Update: Thanks to Kaiser part of the code has been updated.
Here is the final code.

```
<?php 

$custom_terms = get_the_terms(0,'product_tag');
if (
          ! is_wp_error( $custom_terms )
          AND is_array( $custom_terms )
          AND ! empty( $custom_terms )
         )
          {
            foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {

            $term_link = get_term_link( $custom_term );
                echo '<a href="'. esc_url( $term_link ). '" style="font-size: 8pt; margin-right:5px;">'.$custom_term->name.'</a>';
            }
        }

        ?>
```